# Google API: reading docs

Tags: grails, google-api

everyone.

I got some problems with Google API: want to read docs list, but on the first line

```
DocsService client = new DocsService("yourCo-yourAppName-v1");
```

got an exception:

```
Could not initialize class com.google.gdata.client.docs.DocsService. Stacktrace follows:
Caused by NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.gdata.client.docs.DocsService
```

Any ideas and suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your missing a dependency judging by the `NoClassDefFoundError` error.  Make sure you have the correct google API references in the head of your gsp/HTML or the correct imports in your groovy files.

Answer (score 1):

Check this page for the list of external dependencies: https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/java_client_lib

Comment: Thanks, but your limk has no answer and doesn't described all jars I need. Just found all jars required in google and added.